# Teradat update statement

Tags: teradata

The current update statement is

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET  column1 = 1 
WHERE not EXISTS
 ( SELECT  1 FROM  Table2 t2 
   WHERE t2.column2= t1.column2
     AND t2.column1 = 0
 )
AND  t1.column2 > 0
AND t1.column1 = 0
```

The above update statement is fine if I have the value of 0 in column1 in the table Table t2. But I have a special scenario that my table Table t2 is having values as 0 and 1 for column1. In this case there should not be no update. In a single statement i have to handle both the situation.

Scenario 1: Update only if Column1 in the Table t2 having the value of 0

Scenario 2: No update if I Column1 in the Table t2 having the value of both 0 and 1

Can you please help me in this.

Comment: I don't get what you exactly want, but you probably need to add another `(NOT) EXISTS`

Comment: you're saying table t2 has two values in column1, 0 and 1, and when that's the case, you don't want the update to happen?

Comment: yes..whenever my table t2 have two values in column1, 0 and 1 there should not be no update.Update only if table t2 have value in column 1 as 0.

Comment: To add a note,the column1 in table t2 will always have only two values ie 1 and 0.It is a indicator column.